# Delegate call is very slow in ipad app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a view composed of two table views (custom split view) divided by a splitter image. When a user clicks an item on the right view, a modal view pops up and the user edits some values. Once he clicks submit, the edited values must be updated in the respective columns of the table views, on both sides, after a backend web service acknowlegdes success.

I call a delegate method on the custom split view to do the update. The delegate call is very slow, so that I have an activity indicator placed on the table view, but it is not coming on screen during refresh. The updated data comes up properly after some time. If I comment the fetch code, the activity indicator likewise comes up after a while. So obviously the delegate call is very slow. The user gets confused if we don't show any activity happening in the screen during table reload.

1. Why is the activity indicator added to table views not getting displayed?
2. Is there any better approach than what I did so that the user knows some operation is happening in the background so that he can wait?

Comment: I think you may need to show some code. Specifically how you are presenting the activity indicator.

Comment: I guess you're using the main thread to fetch some data from your web service which is not the best way to do that. just keep the code that starts the activity indicator in the main thread and create another one to get your data.

Comment: Thanks Mousa...I called activity indicator for the table in main thread and forked a process to update table it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wait in the delegate.  That will block the UI and the activity indicator.  Return from the delegate method immediately, and use another asynchronous networking callback to finish the update of your tableview element.

Comment: I have given my solution as comments.. Thanks hotpaw for your help too it did help to find.